# Gstreamer: Pipeline is not added and remain nil

Tags: ios, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am working on an iOS app which plays multiple **rtsp** streams at a time.
i have integrated latest Gstreamer binaries and followed demo tutorials from [Here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/tree/gst-sdk/tutorials/xcode%20iOS)

i added a rtsp URL to test my stream , but it is not working.

**Gstreamerbackend** is not adding pipeline.pipeline is nil.
delegate methods are not called
[image]

When application runs , it shows message in the logs "Creating pipeline" , but nothing happens.
shown in screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: You should post actual code, not screenshots of it ...